# Nativescript ImageSource toBase64String outputs null

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am facing an error on the IOS emulator, with the following function when trying to convert an image path to base64 string:

```
imageUploaded(imagePath): void {
  console.log(imagePath);
  this.newImage = new ImageSource();
  this.newImage.fromFile(imagePath)
    .then((success) => {
      if (success) {
        const base64 = this.newImage.toBase64String("jpeg", 100);
        console.log(base64);
      }
    });
}
```

The output of the two console logs are:

> file:///Users/coffee-pot/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0AE2C35-079B-4D8B-AE57-24A3A9A7F931/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0006.PNG

and

> null

I have been caught up in this for so long, and cannot figure it out :/

Thank you in advance for the hints.

**edit**
The following function is the one which uploads the image and emits an event with the file path

```
uploadImage() {
const milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
this.context.authorize()
.then(() => {
  return this.context.present();
})
.then((selection) => {
  selection.forEach((selected) => {
    const ios = selected.ios;
    if (ios && ios.mediaType === PHAssetMediaType.Image) {
      const opt = PHImageRequestOptions.new();
      opt.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current;
      PHImageManager.defaultManager()
      .requestImageDataForAssetOptionsResultHandler(ios, opt,
        (imageData: NSData, dataUTI: string,
         orientation: UIImageOrientation, info: NSDictionary < any, any >) => {
            const folder = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
            const path = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder.path, milliseconds + ".png");
            this.newImage = info.objectForKey("PHImageFileURLKey").toString();
            this.imagePath.emit(this.newImage);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: The outputs as far as I see are from the first console.log where you are printing the `imagePath` - if that is true then most likely you are trying to access a folder you don't have access to which is a common thing in iOS where you have very limited access to the local folders. Make sure you are really having access to the folder.

Comment: I have added the function which i use to upload the image to my app. It is pretty much the standard implementation of the image picker module. So i am not sure how/where to make the changes. :/